# JSON object hook in python unexpectedly changes my plain JSON into nested JSON

Tags: python, json

I am learning Python for school. For my final assignment I decided to create a desktop tasks application with my frontend in HTML/CSS/JS. I wanted to use a .txt file to store my json data in, it's going allright so far.

Right now I am having trouble with reading the JSON data and hooking it to my custom object.
This is my simple class:

```
class Task(dict):
    def __init__(self, title = "no title", description = "no description", priority = 1):
        self.id = str(id(self))
        self.title = title
        self.description = description
        self.priority = priority
        user_tasks["tasks"].append(self.__dict__)
```

When reading JSON from my .txt file I get this as result:

```
[{"id": "2145413512544", "title": "title", "description": "desc", "priority": 3}]
```

If I try to hook the JSON string to my custom Task object like this:

```
json_tasks = json.loads(test, object_hook=Task)
```

it will give me this as a result:

```
'description':'no description',
'id':'1460530367520',
'priority':1,
'title': {'description': 'desc', 'id': '2145413512544', 'priority': 3, 'title': 'title'}
'id':'2145413512544',
'title':'title',
'description':'desc',
'priority':3
```

Does anyone know what's going on here? Help would be appreciated :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your class does not take the right parameters to be used directly as the `object_hook` option.  You need something that takes a single parameter, that will be a dictionary, and calls your class with the individual parameters it needs.  Since the JSON keys and the `__init__()` parameters have the same names, I think this could be as simple as `return Task(**param)`.

Comment: I am sorry but I don't quite understand what you're saying. Where would I call the ```return Task(**param)```?

Comment: You'd put that line in some new function, and then pass that function (instead of `Task` itself) as the `object_hook`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that using `object_hook=Task` gave my entire JSON object as `title` parameter.
I have solved this by creating a function that converts a JSON object to a task, and I passed this function to `object_hook`, like jasonharper said.

```
   user_tasks_json = json.loads(user_tasks_file_content, object_hook=create_task_from_json)
```

The function:

```
def create_task_from_json(json_obj):
    new_task = Task(id = json_obj.get("id"), 
                    title = json_obj.get("title"),
                    description = json_obj.get("description"),
                    priority = json_obj.get("priority"),
                    categoryid = json_obj.get("categoryid"))
```